# Unusual SEO and Redirection Issues After Solana Wallet Integration

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, react

### Overview

Hello Solana community,

We've recently encountered two significant issues upon integrating Solana wallet functionality into our dApp (domain: gray.market), and we're hoping for some guidance or a resolution.

1. **Unexpected Redirection**:
   Some of our users have reported that when they attempt to access our dApp, they are being redirected to https://solanamobile.com/wallets. This behavior is unexpected and has not been coded into our dApp by our team.
2. **SEO Content Overwrite**:
   The more critical issue is a mysterious change in our Google SEO data. Since the integration, the title and description in Google's search results have been replaced with content that does not exist on our site and has never been part of our codebase. Here are the changes observed:

   - Title: **"Choose The Best Wallet"** - should be "Gray Market"
   - Description: **"Discover top Solana wallets and their unique features. Compare and choose the best one for your needs. Check out Phantom, Solflare, and more wallets now."** - should be "Gray Market is a multichain platform providing neo-investment strategies that merges Traditional and Decentralized finance tools."

   These changes are only appearing in Google's search results and not on other search engines like Bing.

We have not made any changes that would cause either of these issues, and they only began after the Solana wallet integration. We are concerned about a potential library or dependency that might be affecting our dApp's behavior and SEO metadata.

Any assistance or insights you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Attached is a screenshot from Google's search results highlighting the SEO issue.

Thank you for your time and help.

### Steps to reproduce

just search "gray.market" on google

### Dependencies:

```
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.4.0",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.35",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.34",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.19.25",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.89.1",
    "bs58": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "14.0.4",
```

i opened this issue: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/2378
But I don't know if it's the right place.

Comment: You may want to open the issue against  https://github.com/anza-xyz/wallet-adapter since solana fork is now maintaned by anza.